# git large file storage / github desktop for mac

Tags: git, macos, github, desktop, git-lfs

I try to install git large file storage on my mac and followed the instructions, but somehow don't manage. I already tried `sudo ./install.sh` but still receive the message: permission denied. Someone who has experience with installing git lfs on github desktop for mac?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What does git-lfs have to do with github desktop?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably best off installing using Homebrew if you can.  That's the simplest and easiest way, and it will also keep you up to date automatically if you normally update Homebrew.

If not, then you can install using the script, but you'll need to mark it executable first (e.g., `chmod +x install.sh`).  That's because, due to the requirements for notarization placed by Apple, Git LFS must distribute a zip file and cannot use a tarball, because tarballs can't be notarized.  Zip files generally don't preserve permissions, causing this problem.

Comment: I suspected it was an executable issue as well, so `chmod +x` should fix the problem. And yes, best to built from a package manager. `macports` is another one if that is your preferred package manager. `sudo port selfupdate && sudo port install git-lfs`